# Roslaunch Sequentially

Tags: ros, roslaunch, include, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need run a lunch's includes(xml) sequentially. That is, one after the other. Until no finish one, don't start the next include.
Is there any way to control this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42945/roslaunch-sequentially/) by [Jose Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3057/jose-luis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 375 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-04**:
roslaunch intentionally does not support that approach, preferring explicit robot state sequencing via messages or service calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No.

Nodes should not need to be run dependently, but wait for services, etc.
If you have another use case that you think can't be solved this way, please provide that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) on 2017-09-01**:
I am running a slam_gmapping node and a bagfile. After successful completion of the bagfile, i need to run mapserver map saver node to save the map.